# force user to enter specific details in textbox input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

i want to force users to enter details for check like "**Check No: 791790 Date: 26/05/2015 ClrDate: 29/05/2015**" in one textbox

the textbox i am using :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control validateblank txtAccCheckDet" id="txtAccCheckDet">
```

i have tried using

`data-inputmask="'alias': '"Check No:''" "Date:" dd/mm/yyyy'" "ClrDate:"'dd/mm/yyyy' data-mask=""`

in textbox but not working.

any help using css,javascript or jquery will be acceptable.

Comment: Why? Would it not be much better to have one textbox per detail? That is a better user experience and better to handle with validation. If a user has to input stuff like `Check No: ` that is asking for errors.

Comment: yes that's better to use separate textbox for each detail but the issue is i dont require this field as a required and this details will be in one row of the table so if i provide separate textbox for each detail then the row will become large horizontally in table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, something like this for example.

```
var regex = '^Check\sNo: [0-9]{6}\sDate:\s[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\sClrDate:\s[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$'
```

And then use something like

```
string.match(regex)
```

To check if the inputed string matches the regex.